# how can i convert my alphabetical index back to Ascii code in C?

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

```
string plaintext = get_string("plaintext;");
  
  for (size_t k = 0; k<strlen(plaintext); k++)
  {
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int m = plaintext[k] -'a' + 1;
    printf("%d", (m + n) % 26);
  }
```

in this piece of code i'm trying to **cipher text that is inputted by the user.**
this: **`(m + n) % 26`** ( m is i'th char of plaintext & n is key) is the **formula** i'm supposed to use.

i tried printing this:

```
printf("%d", (m + n) % 26);
```

as a char, but it won't print out. when i tried printing it out as an int as shown above, ***it outputted a number that is not in Ascii value (for ex.: 1294).***
i figured out that *converting  my index back to Ascii value would solve the problem*, ***but i don't know how to do that.***

- please elaborate in your answer!

Comment: What is the purpose of this? `int m = plaintext[k] -'a' + 1;`

Comment: `(m + n) % 26` will result in a value from `0` to `25`.  In ASCII, none (or few) of these are printable.

Comment: You can take this out of the loop as it only needs to be performed once. `int n = atoi(argv[1]);`

Comment: You probably want to add `n` to `plaintext[k]` and then subtract `26` until it's within the valid range.

Comment: @FiddlingBits That's what the modulo (`%`) is for.

Comment: @tadman Yes.  I see your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a generic ROT*N* type thing then converting back is easy:

```
printf("%c", (m + n) % 26 + 'a' - 1);
```

Where you just have to "undo" what you did earlier.